# No libmongoclient.a under Ubuntu

Tags: c++, mongodb, ubuntu, scons

I'm trying to connect to mongodb under Ubuntu using C++.

I've downloaded 2.2.0 version of the mongodb source code and builded with scons as written in the documentation. But after build I can't see libmongoclient.a. Looks like it's not constructed or something like that. I done the same under the windows 7 and everything works, after build mongoclient.lib is available, but the same steps under Ubuntu seems not working.

Also building only CXX driver not works, after running scons command it asks about not existing boost thread files but I've provided path with --extrapath.

Can someone help me to build libmongoclient.a under Ubuntu?

Comment: What exact scons command line are you using? `scons mongoclient` should build the 'libmongoclient.a.' file. I would also recommend using the latest production release (i.e. 2.2.2).

Comment: do you have a directory called ./build/<platform>/normal/client_build/ - that's where libmongoclient.a will be.

Answer (score 1):

scons mongoclient should build the 'libmongoclient.a.'

Thanks a lot Stennie for your help